# bash./configure :permission denied

Tags: elementary-os

I'm using elementary Os. I tried to install vlc tar.
Got an error after extracting package
"$./configure"
bash:./configure:permission denied

Comment: 1. List the permissions of the configure script. 2. Is vlc available in your package repository? 3. Should you run configure with root permissions?

Comment: Please provide the exact input and output, properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear from your question which part you typed.

Try

```
chmod +x configure
./configure
```